# Is it dangerous to use the following in vector?

Tags: c++

I have a member variable `vector<Foo> m_list`

In some methods, I create the auto variable a in Foo type

```
Foo a;
m_list.push_back(a)
```

Is it possible that m_list[0] becomes invalid?

```
Class Foo 
{
    vector<int> _colors;
    vector<int> _flowers;
}
```

Comment: Sure it's possible, but `ClassA` shouldn't let that happen.

Comment: Sorry what are your concerns exactly? You create an instance of ClassA on the stack and then you push_back which will copy the object

Comment: If your Class is appropriately constructed(copy constructor, good constructor, destructor) then I am not sure that any issues will arise...

Comment: If my class does not define copy constructor and is not POD, that will be an issue, right?

Comment: @Lilshieste the compiler will supply a copy constructor so long as you have not defined a default constructor, copy constructor and some other things I can't remember at the moment

Comment: @AdamLee There is a default copy constructor. If it cannot be generated for some reason, or cannot be used, then it won't compile. Whether default copy-constructor is sufficient for correct behaviour is up to you.

Comment: @Lilshieste What? The compiler can auto generate a copy constructor. Adam: The answer to your question depends on what `ClassA` does. Is it managing resources, and violating the Rule of Three? If so, your code is broken.

Comment: My class contains some other vector, so I think if I do not provide copy constructor myself, the default generated compiler cannot automatically copy the vector, is that true?

Comment: Sorry, y'all are right. For some reason I was thinking of it not having a copy constructor in the sense that it had been `delete`d.

Comment: @AdamLee Looking at your latest edit, there's nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be worried about what will happen to `m_list[0]` once the local variable `a` goes out of scope. Don't be. `push_back` actually pushes a *copy* of `a` into `m_list`. Now; that may cause other problems if you were expecting `a` and `m_list[0]` to be the same thing, but as long as `ClassA` has a functioning copy constructor (and based on your edit, it does), trying to access a destroyed object won't be one of them.

Comment: Please see my updated question. My class Foo contains some vectors and I don't define the copy constructor. Will this cause some random issue?

Comment: Nope. `vector` defines a copy constructor that copies all the elements, and `int` is trivially copyable. The compiler's default copy constructor for `Foo` will work fine.